# Using Boost::asio in Winx64: I'm stuck, need to figure out how to build libboost_system_xxxx.lib for x64

Tags: c++, windows, boost, 64-bit

Unlike this question:

[Linker Error while building application using Boost Asio in Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704294/linker-error-while-building-application-using-boost-asio-in-visual-studio-c-200)

I need an x64 build of the lib files... I'm not even sure how to get started. I'm reading here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/more/getting_started/windows.html

Or, more generally, how do I build boost for x64?

Comment: See this question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302208/how-do-you-build-the-x64-boost-libraries-on-windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302208/how-do-you-build-the-x64-boost-libraries-on-windows)

Comment: thanks, that article says the same thing as Maik above, and it seems to be working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not on Windows, but I guess adding address-model=64 to the bjam invocation should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this is explained in the official documentation, right [here](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/advanced/invocation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the command line I ended up using:

C:\Program Files (x86)\boost\boost_1_38>bjam --build-dir=c:\boost --build-type=complete --toolset=msvc-9.0 address-model=64 architecture=x86 --with-system

Answer (score 0):

I was in the process of figuring this out myself recently, when attempting to port a 32-bits program that made use of the 32-bits binaries provided by BoostPro. I couldn't download x64 binaries from BoostPro for free; they only provide free 32-bits libraries. But then I found that there were free binaries available from this site:

http://boost.teeks99.com/

I realize this may not answer your question if you want some customized build, but it could save you a lot of time if a regular build is fine. Unpacked, it's huge (7Gb) but it seems to be complete and working.